# 405 Error (xhr.status) on AJAX call to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to troubleshoot an AJAX call. I got an xhr.status error message of 405. Here's my code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '/v/js/swatch.js', //Where to make Ajax calls
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
    success:function(response){

        $.parseJSON(response);

    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status); //throw any errors
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm using $.ajax instead of $.getJSON for troubleshooting purposes (I don't think it's relevant here, that's a super complex issue that I'm working through step by step). swatch.js is set up as a JSON data sheet FYI and I'm trying to parse it as text.

I couldn't seem to understand what the 405 error specifies but from what I read it has something to do with the 'post' method. I'm not technically posting any data here so I'm assuming it has something to do with that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may not be posting an data but you are using the post (`type: 'post',`). Just remove that line and you'll make a get request. which shouldn't cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to request data from js file then your "dataType" field must be 'script'. If you make the ajax call with dateType: 'script' then It will load entire js file to your document. you can use the json object directly as defined in js file.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '/v/js/swatch.js', //Where to make Ajax calls
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'script', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
    success:function(response){

        console.log('script loaded')

    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status); //throw any errors
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This threw a 405 xhr.status as well.